# Make Django models entries unique to each user

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am working on a system in Django where users will enter a stock symbol, that will be saved (using models). And when they login, they will see the stock symbols they entered. However, as it currently is everyone sees the same entries, which is a collection of what they have all entered.

Here is my models.py file:

```
class StockTickerSymbol(models.Model):
    StockName = models.CharField(max_length=6)


    test = models.CharField(default="Test", max_length=100)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Added', default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.StockName
```

and here is my views.py file:

```
def fav(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    favorites_list = StockTickerSymbol.objects.order_by('-added_date')
    context_dict = {'favorites': favorites_list}

    return render_to_response('favorites/favorites.html', context_dict, context)
```

Is there anyway I can have users only see their own entries, instead of seeing everyones entries? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your model needs a reference to the User model, so you can limit the queryset to the requesting user like so:

**Model**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class StockTickerSymbol(models.Model):
    StockName = models.CharField(max_length=6)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)

    test = models.CharField(default="Test", max_length=100)
    added_date = models.DateTimeField('Date Added', default=datetime.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.StockName
```

**View**

```
def fav(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)

    favorites_list = StockTickerSymbol.objects.filter(user=request.user).order_by('-added_date')
    context_dict = {'favorites': favorites_list}

    return render_to_response('favorites/favorites.html', context_dict, context)
```

Comment: Thank you this is what I was looking for. But, is there anyway I can have the user's username selected by default instead of having them select it from a list of usernames?